# Is there a way to invoke AuraEnabled methods form browser's dev tools?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura-enabled

as title states I am looking for a way to invoke aura enabled functions by using only browser capabilities not via javascript written inside org, especially in lwc context. In the end when we add a button or anything to invoke those functions, they are all post/get methods to Salesforce, so I wonder is there a way to mimic it via browser?

PS: This is needed for security check for portal application, so I am looking for ways to test our security, before reaching a proffesional.

Comment: My money is on a strong no; the documentation for AuraEnabled says that it exposes Apex methods for LWCs and Aura components.  There is separate documentation for exposing Apex as REST resources, which indicates a different level of exposure.  I'm not adding this as an answer though because ultimately I'm not certain.  Have you looked at the network tab of your dev tools to see what's being passed back in a request when an LWC calls one?

Comment: When you say `via browser`, you mean a tool in browser? You can try it yourself, just pass all params via postman and check once.

Comment: Yes, exactly, currently I figured out I can use resend method of Firefox, that works actually. Just change classname and method name, I am able to manipulate

Comment: @oozkan as you already found, this works pretty well if you're able to obtain a sid cookie and an auraToken for invocations.
This won't be a supported mechanism but let's say it hasn't changed in a few years :)

Comment: For anyone who comes across this - in 2023 it seems that they started sending auraToken in cookies instead of JSON config as before :/